# How to delete a list of filenames without path that are matched in multiple subdirectories?

Tags: delete, find, rm

How to delete a list of filenames without path that are matched in multiple subdirectories?

Delete_list.txt may contain (each filename is per line):

```
a.jpg
b.jpg
c.jpg
```

These files may exists in multiple subdirectories. I want to delete them all. I tried but no success:

```
for f in $(delete_list.txt); do find . -name "$f" -type f -delete  ; done
```

2nd try

```
  f in $(delete_list.txt);  do find . -name "$f" -type f -exec rm -f {} \;
```

3rd try

```
while IFS= read -r file ; do rm -r -- "$file" ; done < delete_list.txt
```

4rth try

```
for f in $(delete_list.txt); do if [ -f $f ]; then rm $f; fi; done
```

Comment: Could you please rewrite the script so that each command is in separate lines and indented where appropriate? This is very hard to read. It seems like you have 3 different attempts of the script all jumbled together.

Comment: Note: even if it's not recommended, and I strongly advise against it, the syntax is `$(<delete_list.txt)`, which is a substitute for `$(cat delete_list.txt)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a shell such as bash that supports arrays you could assemble all of the names into a single `find` predicate

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a namep=()

while IFS= read -r name; do 
  namep+=( -name "$name" -o )
done < delete_list.txt

unset namep[-1]    # remove the extraneous trailing -o

find . -type f \( "${namep[@]}" \) -print
```

Change `-print` to `-delete` (or `-print -delete`) only when you are certain it is finding the right files.

Comment: So fast! In few minutes deletes many thousand files under thousand subdirectories!!! Can you explain more what is "array" in bash and how it is utilized / used in the system? And why it is much quicker than my option?

Comment: What it means "extraneous leading"?

Comment: @EliasEstatistics we want the sequence to start with a `-name` not a `-o`, so we remove the 0th array element

Comment: ... I just modified the sequence a bit - maybe it's clearer this way?

Comment: I must read about arrays in linux and "extraneous leading". Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me. It is deleting all matched filenames in the given files under all subdirectories.

However, it is extremely slow. The delete_list.txt contains around 100 filenames to be found under 250 thousands+ subdirectories.

```
 while read -r FILE; do echo "$(find . -name "$FILE" -type f -delete): $FILE"; done < delete_list.txt
```